# asp.net web api: only during sql connection - HTTP 500 Error occurs : Local host is currently unable to handle request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, localhost, asp.net-core-webapi, http-error

The Web Api throws HTTP 500 error when it has to reference values from sql database.
**https://localhost:44304/api/values** 
This works fine.

But,
**https://localhost:44304/api/User**
throws HTTP 500 Error - Local host is currently unable to handle request

The API is a simple test one, which has to retrieve data from User table in SQL database.

```
    private readonly string connectionString = 
    "Server=MyServerName\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;user 
    id=dbuser;password=dbuserpass;";
```

**The data access file:**

```
   namespace UserLogin.Models
   {
    public partial class User
    {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    }
   }
```

No changes being done to any  portions of the default code after creating the Web API Component.

**Note: using udl, the test connection to the database was successful.**

Thanks for help.

Comment: Post the code for Controller and action method.

Comment: Thanks @Thangadurai.  The issue was figured out as a stored procedure error which was recitified and now it works fine.